# What is the difference between using and await using? And how can I decide which one to use?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, idisposable, c#-8.0, iasyncdisposable

I've noticed that in some case, Visual Studio recommends to do this

```
await using var disposable = new Disposable();
// Do something
```

Instead of this

```
using var disposable = new Disposable();
// Do something
```

What is the difference between `using` and `await using`?

How should I decide which one to use?

Comment: It looks like you can only use `await using` with a `IAsyncDisposable` and you can only use `using` with a `IDisposable` since neither one inherits from the other.  The only time you can use either is if the concrete class implements both and then it depends on if you are writing asynchronous code or not.

Comment: Somewhat related: [What's the recommended way to deal with leaked IAsyncDisposable instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677445/whats-the-recommended-way-to-deal-with-leaked-iasyncdisposable-instances)

Answer (score 220, accepted):

### Classic sync using

Classic using calls the `Dispose()` method of an object implementing the `IDisposable` interface.

```
using var disposable = new Disposable();
// Do Something...
```

Is equivalent to

```
IDisposable disposable = new Disposable();
try
{
    // Do Something...
}
finally
{
    disposable.Dispose();
}
```

### New async await using

The new await using calls and await the `DisposeAsync()` method of an object implementing the `IAsyncDisposable` interface.

```
await using var disposable = new AsyncDisposable();
// Do Something...
```

Is equivalent to

```
IAsyncDisposable disposable = new AsyncDisposable();
try
{
    // Do Something...
}
finally
{
    await disposable.DisposeAsync();
}
```

---

The [IAsyncDisposable Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable?) was added in `.NET Core 3.0` and `.NET Standard 2.1`.

> In .NET, classes that own unmanaged resources usually implement the [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable) interface to provide a mechanism for releasing unmanaged resources synchronously. However, in some cases they need to **provide an asynchronous mechanism for releasing unmanaged resources in addition to (or instead of) the synchronous one**. Providing such a mechanism enables the consumer to perform resource-intensive dispose operations without blocking the main thread of a GUI application for a long time.
>
> The [IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable.disposeasync) method of this interface returns a [ValueTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask) that represents the asynchronous dispose operation. Classes that own unmanaged resources implement this method, and the consumer of these classes calls this method on an object when it is no longer needed.

Comment: Since `using` is syntactic sugar anyway, why not just make using handle both cases?

Comment: Probably to be explicit.

Comment: @Squirrelkiller Because they're not doing the same thing. If you have an object implementing both interfaces, do you dispose of it synchronously or asynchronously? What about an object only implementing `IAsyncDisposable` inside a non-async context?

Answer (score 31):

Justin Lessard's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610350/what-is-the-difference-between-using-and-await-using-and-how-can-i-decide-which/58610351#58610351) explains the difference between `using` and `await using`, so I'll focus on which one to use. There are two cases: either the two methods `Dispose`/`DisposeAsync` are complementary, or they are doing something different.

1. If the methods are complementary, which is the common case, you can call either one of them and the result will be the same: the unmanaged resources will be released. There is no reason to call both of them, sequentially. If you do, the second call will be a no-op: the resources are already released, so there will be nothing more to do. Choosing which one to call is easy: if you are in a synchronous context, call the `Dispose()` (use the `using`). If you are in an asynchronous context, call the `await DisposeAsync()` (use the `await using`)¹.
2. If the methods are doing something different, you should read the documentation and decide which behavior is more suitable for the scenario at hand. For example let's talk about the [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) class, that implements both interfaces (`IDisposable` and `IAsyncDisposable`). The `Dispose` method releases the unmanaged resources as expected, but the `DisposeAsync` is doing something more than that: it also awaits the completion of any callbacks that are currently running. Let's make an experiment to demonstrate this difference:

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
using (new Timer(_ => Thread.Sleep(1000), null, 0, Timeout.Infinite))
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
Console.WriteLine($"Duration: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds:#,0} msec");
```

We create a timer that fires after 0 msec, so practically immediately, then we wait for 100 msec to be sure that the callback has been invoked (it is invoked on a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread), and then we dispose the timer synchronously. Here is the output of [this experiment](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TN88yn):

```
Duration: 102 msec
```

Now let's switch from `using` to `await using`. Here is the output of the [second experiment](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IVS3Vk):

```
Duration: 1,005 msec
```

The implicit call to `DisposeAsync` returned a `ValueTask` that completed only after the completion of the timer's callback.

So in the case of a `Timer`, choosing between `using` and `await using` is not just a choice that depends on the context. You might prefer to use the synchronous `using` in an async context, because you don't care about the callback (you know that it's not harmful to let it become fire-and-forget). Or you might be in a synchronous context but you might prefer the behavior of `await using`, because fire-and-forget is unacceptable. In that case you'll have to abandon the convenience of `using`, and invoke instead the `DisposeAsync` explicitly in a `finally` block:

```
var timer = new Timer(_ => Thread.Sleep(1000), null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
try { Thread.Sleep(100); }
finally { timer.DisposeAsync().AsTask().Wait(); }
```

¹ <sub>Be aware, especially if you are writing a library, that the `await using` captures the synchronization context by default. In case this is undesirable, which usually is for library code, you'll have to configure it with `ConfigureAwait(false)`. This has some implications that are discussed here: [How do I get the "await using" syntax correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886713/how-do-i-get-the-await-using-syntax-correct)</sub>