# JToken.WriteToAsync does not write to JsonWriter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, request, json.net, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm trying to create a middleware that changes the request in a certain way. I am able to read it and change the content but I cannot figure out how to correctly setup the stream writers to create a new body. When I call `normalized.WriteToAsync(jsonWriter)` the `MemoryStream` remains empty and consequently I receive the *A non-empty request body is required.* exception. What am I missing here? This is what I have so far:

```cs
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.ContentType == "application/json" && context.Request.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        using var scope = _logger.BeginScope("NormalizeJson");
        try
        {
            using var requestReader = new HttpRequestStreamReader(context.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8);
            using var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(requestReader);

            var json = await JToken.LoadAsync(jsonReader);
            var normalized = _normalize.Visit(json); // <-- Modify json and return JToken

            // Create new Body
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
            var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(requestWriter);
            await normalized.WriteToAsync(jsonWriter); // <-- At this point the MemoryStream has still 0 length.

            var content = new StreamContent(memoryStream.Rewind()); // <-- Use helper extension to Seek.Begin = 0                 
            context.Request.Body = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Scope().Exceptions.Push(e);
        }
    }

    await _next(context);
}
```

---

**Demo** for LINQPad etc.:

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    var token = JToken.FromObject(new User { Name = "Bob" });

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
    var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(requestWriter);
    await token.WriteToAsync(jsonWriter); 
    memoryStream.Length.Dump(); // <-- MemoryStream.Length = 0
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid converting it to a `string` first.

Comment: Since you're writing to a `MemoryStream`, why use `async` at all?

Comment: @dbc I don't have any clever answer to that but consistency. Would you use something else instead?

Comment: Yes, I'd just do [`WriteTo()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_WriteTo.htm), declare victory and move on?

Comment: @dbc I've just tested it and unfortunately the `MemoryStream` is still empty :\ There must be some piece of magic missing here...

Comment: @dbc See the _demo_ below the actual code. This is the minimal example that reproduces this issue.

Comment: @t3chb0t When I call `Flush()` on `jsonWriter` the memory stream get data, so you probably need to wrap the writer in a `using`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to properly flush and close your `JsonTextWriter` and `StreamWriter` in order to fully populate the `memoryStream`, like so:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
// StreamWriter implements IAsyncDisposable
// Leave the underlying stream open
await using (var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, leaveOpen: true)) 
{
    var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(requestWriter); // But JsonTextWriter does not implement IAsyncDisposable, only IDisposable!
    try
    {
        await token.WriteToAsync(jsonWriter); 
    }
    finally
    {
        await jsonWriter.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ft2IuG).

Or, since you're writing to a `MemoryStream`, there's really no nead to use `async` at all, and instead you can do:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, leaveOpen: true)) // Leave the underlying stream open
using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(requestWriter))
{
    token.WriteTo(jsonWriter); 
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VMbenS).

Notes:

- Note the use of [`await using`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58610350/3744182) for the `StreamWriter`.  This syntax guarantees that the `StreamWriter` will be flushed and closed asynchronously, and can be used on any object that implements [`IAsyncDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable?view=netcore-3.1).  (This only really matters if you were writing to a file stream or other non-memory stream.)
- It seems that neither [`JsonTextWriter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm) nor the base class [`JsonWriter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter.htm) implement `IAsyncDisposable`, so I had to asynchronously close the JSON writer manually rather than via a `using` statement.  The outer `await using` should ensure that the underlying `StreamWriter` is not left open in the event of an exception.
- JSON [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-8.1) specifies that *Implementations MUST NOT add a byte order mark (U+FEFF) to the beginning of a networked-transmitted JSON text*.  Thus, when constructing a `StreamWriter`, it is recommended to pass an encoding such as [`new UTF8Encoding(false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Text_UTF8Encoding__ctor_System_Boolean_) that does not prepend a BOM. Alternatively, if you just want UTF-8, the [`StreamWriter` constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-5.0) will *create a StreamWriter with UTF-8 encoding without a Byte-Order Mark (BOM)* if you do not specify one yourself and leave a default value for that parameter as is shown in the code above.

Comment: What a combo of awaits and close and usings and leave-open! :-O