# JsonSerializer size limited to 7168 chars/bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

Consider this sample code:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
                using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    this.GetSerializer().Serialize(writer, data, typeof(T));

                    // convert stream to string
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    var reader = new StreamReader(ms);
                    var textToSend = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
```

Serializer obtained from this method:

```
private JsonSerializer GetSerializer()
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };

            serializer.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd\\THH:mm:ss.fffZ" });
            return serializer;
        }
```

When I serialize 'data' it produces memory stream with 7168 bytes and when I convert to string I see how message being truncated. Searched but can't find what might be causing this limit?

Comment: You need to dispose the `JsonTextWriter` and `StreamWriter` before accessing the memory stream, both have buffers that need flushing.  See: [JToken.WriteToAsync does not write to JsonWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60916536/3744182) which shows an example of disposing the `StreamWriter` without having to dispose the underlying stream.

Comment: Like @dbc said, you should move your `MemorySteam` reading to after your 2 `using` blocks. The `MemoryStream` should technically also be in a `using` block of its own. At the end of that block is where I'd read from the stream.

Comment: Shall we close as a duplicate of [JToken.WriteToAsync does not write to JsonWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60916536/3744182) since the answer is basically identical?

Comment: If you respond I can mark you q as answer