# JToken.WriteToAsync dosen't write to stream correctly

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to write a JToken to a stream asynchronously. And I referred to [JToken.WriteToAsync does not write to JsonWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60915876/jtoken-writetoasync-does-not-write-to-jsonwriter).
However, the stream output is `?[]`, while `ToString()` output is `[]`.  Why does the stream contain extra bytes at the beginning?

My code is below:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    JArray arr = new JArray();

    //var c = JToken.FromObject("abc");
    //arr.Add(c);

    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    await using (var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(requestWriter); 
        try
        {
            await arr.WriteToAsync(jsonWriter);
        }
        finally
        {
            await jsonWriter.CloseAsync();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, checked((int)stream.Length)));

        Console.WriteLine(arr.ToString());

    }
}
```

Why stream output is not correct?
The Json.net's version is 13.0.1.

Comment: MemoryStream is used for test, not for production

Comment: Add a catch to that try and see whether there is an exception. That would help you a lot.

Comment: You are accessing the `stream` before the `StreamWriter requestWriter` has been disposed.  Try moving the call to `stream.GetBuffer()` to outside the `await using (var requestWriter ...`.

Comment: @tanxin - In addition to answering your question, I updated my answer to [JToken.WriteToAsync does not write to JsonWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60915876/3744182) to not include the BOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

Your problem has nothing to do with asynchronous writing. Your problem is that [`Encoding.UTF8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8?view=net-5.0):

> returns a UTF8Encoding object that provides a Unicode byte order mark (BOM).

The extra `?` you are seeing is that BOM.  To prevent the BOM from being written, use [`new UTF8Encoding(false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Text_UTF8Encoding__ctor_System_Boolean_) when writing.  Or, you could just do `new StreamWriter(stream, leaveOpen: true)` as the [`StreamWriter` constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-5.0) will use a *UTF-8 encoding without a Byte-Order Mark (BOM)* by default.

**Details**

Your problem can be reproduced more simply as follows:

```
JArray arr = new JArray();

var stream = new MemoryStream();

using (var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, leaveOpen: true))
using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(requestWriter))
{
    arr.WriteTo(jsonWriter);
}

var resultJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, checked((int)stream.Length));
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, checked((int)stream.Length)));
Console.WriteLine(resultJson);
Console.WriteLine(arr.ToString());

Assert.AreEqual(arr.ToString(), resultJson);
```

The assertion fails with the following message:

```
NUnit.Framework.AssertionException:   Expected string length 2 but was 3. Strings differ at index 0.
```

And with the following output from `BitConverter.ToString()`:

`EF-BB-BF-5B-5D`

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BtRITg).

The `5B-5D` are the brackets, but what are the three preamble characters `EF-BB-BF`?  A quick search shows it to be the [UTF-8 byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).  Since [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-8.1) specifies that *Implementations MUST NOT add a byte order mark (U+FEFF) to the beginning of a networked-transmitted JSON text* you should omit the BOM by using `new UTF8Encoding(false)`.  Thus your code should look like:

```
JArray arr = new JArray();

var stream = new MemoryStream();

await using (var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, new UTF8Encoding(false), leaveOpen: true))
{
    var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(requestWriter); 
    try
    {
        await arr.WriteToAsync(jsonWriter);
    }
    finally
    {
        await jsonWriter.CloseAsync();
    }
}

var resultJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, checked((int)stream.Length));
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, checked((int)stream.Length)));
Console.WriteLine(resultJson);
Console.WriteLine(arr.ToString());

Assert.AreEqual(arr.ToString(), resultJson);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IZdRzL).