# Do I need to call DisposeAsync on a FileStream when using it with using clause?

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, using

Consider the following code taken from the the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0):

```
using FileStream createStream = File.Create(fileName);
// ...write to stream etc..
await createStream.DisposeAsync(); // <- isn't this done automatically because of the using clause in the first line`?
```

Isn't calling the `DisposeAsync()` method superfluous?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between using and await using? And how can I decide which one to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610350/what-is-the-difference-between-using-and-await-using-and-how-can-i-decide-which)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`using` clause will call `Dispose()` method, not `DisposeAsync()`. It's not the same since `Dispose()` is blocking call and the presence of `DisposeAsync` suggests that dispose might be resource intensive and so you don't want to call `Dispose` if you can instead call `DisposeAsync`.

The code as written will first call `DisposeAsync` and then at the end of the scope it will also call `Dispose`. We can assume it's harmless because implementing class should have a check that resource was already disposed so second `Dispose` should do nothing. However, if you use C#8+, you can use `await using`:

```
await using FileStream createStream = File.Create(fileName);
```

This is the same as `using` but it will  call `await DisposeAsync()` at the end of the scope, instead of `Dispose`. So just like you do now, but automatically (and in finally block). It works with `IAsyncDisposable` target (such as `FileStream` which inherits from `Stream` which implements `IAsyncDisposable`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the whole snippet here:

```cs
public static async Task Main()
{
    var weatherForecast = new WeatherForecast
    {
        // ...
    };

    string fileName = "WeatherForecast.json";
    using FileStream createStream = File.Create(fileName);
    await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(createStream, weatherForecast);
    await createStream.DisposeAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
}
```

`using` declaration will call `Dispose` in generated finally block at the end of the current scope, the problem here is that the file is accessed before the end of the scope:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
```

So the `await createStream.DisposeAsync();` is actually needed otherwise the file will not be accessible (or even if it would be - potentially not all data will be flushed).

In this concrete case switching to [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) (the one with braces, also both `using` statement and declaration actually support handling `IAsyncDisposable`) would be cleaner and will make `await createStream.DisposeAsync();` call redundant:

```cs
await using (FileStream createStream = File.Create(fileName))
{
    await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(createStream, weatherForecast);
}

Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :-) I accepted the other one, but your's is also great - however I can accept only one ):

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf was glad to help) Though I think mine is a better one and closer to the sample code =)

Comment: yes it's closer to the sample code, but that's also the issue as the questions was more about async dispose and not the complete code. Two view points possible here ;-)

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf this was a joke))) It is up to you to decide what answer better your question)