# How do IDisposable and IAsyncDisposable both work together?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, iasyncdisposable

The class below is not `sealed`, which means it is considered inheritable. I took IDisposable/IAsyncDisposable implementation from [here](https://github.com/carlst99/DbgCensus/blob/cc19d4282e774826e98ca4a3287efea1ea0152a0/DbgCensus.EventStream/BaseEventStreamClient.cs#L345) and I'm trying to understand why the `.Dispose` calls are duplicated in both Dispose and DisposeAsync. Will someone be able to explain to me how it works more deeply/or I would say low level, so I actually know how to use it in future?

```cs
public class Client : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger<Client> _logger;
    private readonly Channel<string> _outputChannel;
    private ClientWebSocket? _clientWebSocket;
    private CancellationTokenSource? _cancellationSource;
    private Task _receiving = Task.CompletedTask;
    private Task _sending = Task.CompletedTask;

    public Client(ILoggerFactory? loggerFactory = default)
    {
        _logger = (loggerFactory ?? NullLoggerFactory.Instance).CreateLogger<Client>();
    }

    public bool IsDisposed { get; protected set; }

    ...

    /// <summary>
    ///     Checks if this object has been disposed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException">Thrown if the object has been disposed.</exception>
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    protected void DoDisposeChecks()
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(Client));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Disposes of managed and unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposeManaged">A value indicating whether or not to dispose of managed resources.</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposeManaged)
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposeManaged)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Socket {Id} is disposing", Id);

            _clientWebSocket?.Dispose();
            _cancellationSource?.Dispose();

            _outputChannel.Writer.TryComplete();

            _logger.LogDebug("Socket {Id} disposed", Id);
        }

        IsDisposed = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Asynchronously disposes of managed resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A task representing the asynchronous operation.</returns>
    protected virtual ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore()
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
        {
            return default;
        }

        _logger.LogDebug("Socket {Id} is disposing", Id);

        _clientWebSocket?.Dispose();
        _cancellationSource?.Dispose();

        _outputChannel.Writer.TryComplete();

        _logger.LogDebug("Socket {Id} disposed", Id);

        IsDisposed = true;

        return default;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeAsyncCore().ConfigureAwait(false);
        Dispose(false);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: That class doesn't have a finalizer so shouldn't be calling  GC.SuppressFinalize at all.

Comment: @Liam, https://github.com/carlst99/DbgCensus/blob/cc19d4282e774826e98ca4a3287efea1ea0152a0/DbgCensus.EventStream/BaseEventStreamClient.cs doesn't seem to have it too (the place I took this implementation from).

Comment: I mean I might hit myself in the head with a hammer, doesn't mean you should copy me :D

Comment: @Liam, true. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync#implement-the-async-dispose-pattern Microsoft's implementation doesn't have the duplicated calls in both .Dispose and .DisposeAsync

Comment: Someone seems to have very much over thought this. Seems to me this should have a simple `IDisposable` with a Dispose call. This is a common anti pattern you see around. IMO it's premature optimisation.

Comment: the docs specifically said, *"If obj does not have a finalizer or the GC has already signaled the finalizer thread to run the finalizer, the call to the SuppressFinalize method has no effect"* in regard to `GC.SuppressFinalize`. as for the original question, `IDisposable` called on synchronous run while `IAsyncDisposable` called on asyc only, [this been discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677445/whats-the-recommended-way-to-deal-with-leaked-iasyncdisposable-instances).